# Complex inner product aren't inner products.

Tags: linear-algebra

An inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ satisfies the following properties:

Let $u$, $v$, and $w$ be vectors and $\alpha$ be a scalar, then:

1. $\langle u+v,w\rangle=\langle u,w\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle$ and  $\langle \alpha v,w\rangle=\alpha\langle v,w\rangle$ (**Linearity in first coordinate**).
2. $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$ (**Symmetry**) .
3. $\langle v,v\rangle\ge 0$ and $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $v=0$ (**Positive definiteness**).

This the general definition of inner products, but in complex vector spaces the symmetry part is $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$, how can be possible? this is supposed to be the same symmetry of the general properties above, btw what's the difinition of $\overline{\langle u,v\rangle}$?

**EDIT**

I know how to prove $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$, what I wanna know is why this is called an inner product, because we don't have $\langle u,v\rangle={\langle v,u\rangle}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the complex conjugate. And if you restrict $x\mapsto \overline{x}$ to the reals, you get the identity.

Comment: Note that in the complex case you can't have both symmetry and positive definiteness. It turns out that positive definiteness is the more useful property - by taking the square root you can give a complex number a length - and this generalises. But to get a positive definite form you need to introduce the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to preserve all of these 3 properties in complex field.  We have to choose the least important one to *sacrifice*.

Linearity is the foundation of linear algebra, and positive definiteness is required to make inner product a [metric](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).  Therefore, we abandon symmetry.

Comment: but what's the general definition of inner products?

Comment: An inner product space is a [normed vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_space) satisfying the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_equality#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about the complex inner product (not a normal real inner product), you cannot apply the real inner product properties. If you check the property for complex inner product (the Hermitian inner product), you can find the property you are talking about. In fact, if you apply real numbers on this Hermitian inner product, you get the same result as apply them on the real inner product.

You can have a look at this document.

http://www2.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it doesn't answer my question, I know how to prove $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$, my question is the requirement to be an inner product: this is not an inner product because we don't have $\langle u,v\rangle={\langle v,u\rangle}$.

Comment: @user42912 Since you are talking about the complex inner product (not a normal real inner product), you cannot apply the real inner product properties. If you check the property for complex inner product (the Hermitian inner product), you can find the property you are talking about. In fact, if you apply real numbers on this Hermitian inner product, you get the same result as apply them on the real inner product.

Comment: what's the general definition of inner products?

Comment: @user42912 for real inner product, the properties are what you stated in your question.

Comment: @user42912 It really depends on whether or not your scalar field is the complex numbers or the real numbers! We define the inner product differently for these two. However, notice that the more general condition $\langle u, v \rangle = \overline{\langle v, u \rangle}$ simplifies to the $\langle u, v \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$ if $\langle v, u \rangle$ is real.

Comment: I thought the definition I gave in my question was the general definition of inner products

Comment: @user42912 the one in the question is the one for real numbers, there is another one for complex, that's the more general one (it works for both real and complex numbers).

Comment: I think I got it! thanks